# Why does Django only serve files containing a space?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a basic Django application. For testing / development purposes I'm trying to serve the static content of the website using Django's development server as per http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#howto-static-files.

My urls.py contains:

```
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),

    (r'^(?P<page_name>\S*)$', 'Blah.content.views.index'),

    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': 'C:/Users/My User/workspace/Blah/media',
         'show_indexes': True})
```

However, when I try to access a file such as http://localhost:8000/static/images/Logo.jpg Django gives me a 404 error claiming that "No Page matches the given query."

When I try to access a file such as http://localhost:8000/static/images/Blah%20Logo.jpg it serves the file!

What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have wrong patterns order in `urls.py`.

When you try to retrieve path *without* space it matches:

```
(r'^(?P<page_name>\S*)$', 'Blah.content.views.index'),
```

not `static.serve` and of course you have not such page, But when you try to access path *with* space it matches proper `static.serve` pattern because it is more generic and allows spaces.

To solve this problem just swap those patterns.